# Is there a way to make eclipse report a general "catch (Exception e)" as an error/warning (in java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, static-analysis

I'm trying to encourage a best practice of not catching general exceptions in Java code.  eg:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (Exception e) {  // bad!
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to flag this as an error/warning in Eclipse?

I know PMD picks this up, but I'd rather avoid integrating it into everyone's build environment at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) eclipse plugin to do the same. Check 'IllegalCatch' section at [documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html)

Comment: Checkstyle is what you want. A reasonably simple to configure eclipse plugin which can report style problems in the code base as warnings or errors.  Even better, hook it up with Hudson for a great Continuous Integration environment.

Answer (score 3):

[`FindBugs`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION) can report this:

> `REC`: `Exception` is caught when `Exception` is not thrown (`REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION`)
>
> This method uses a `try-catch` block that catches `Exception` objects, but `Exception` is not thrown within the `try` block, and `RuntimeException` is not explicitly caught. It is a common bug pattern to say `try { ... } catch (Exception e) { something }` as a shorthand for catching a number of types of exception each of whose catch blocks is identical, but this construct also accidentally catches `RuntimeException` as well, masking potential bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Running the FindBugs, CheckStyle or PMD on every build would slow everyone's builds down, and I imagine that is why you are looking at the Eclipse approach.  Unfortunately, that may also be problematic, depending on availability (and robustness) of plugins.  Plus, you'll still take a performance hit in incremental and (especially) full project builds.

Another alternative would be to set up a [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) continuous integration server and configure it to run style checkers, coverage tools and so on, tracking the results over time using the [Sonar plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it's not in the list at Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings, and thus not possible - unless you fancy writing your own ecliple plugin.